# Replace immediate next string/word coming after a particular pattern

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have a pattern like this `file.py ARG` in my file

I want to search the pattern `file.py` and replace the `ARG` with a new value (*without* removing double quote `"` at the end) in all the matches.

The input file looks like this:

```
"SEC":"NEW"
"CMD":"/usr/local/file.py ARG"
```

I want to replace `ARG` (here `ARG` is not constant it could be any text) using the command line. So I am looking for pattern to search `file.py` and replace the text without removing the double quote.

Comment: Is your data in a JSON file (or YAML, or TOML)? If so, could you please post more context for the line in the file to make it easier to locate with a command-line JSON parser, please?

Comment: @they, I updated the original post , it does not have more data.

Answer (score 0):

By the input you gave in your question:

```
sed 's/\(file.py\) \+.\+"$/\1 NEW_VALUE"/'
```

`sed` - stream editor
`s` - command substitute
`/\(file.py\) \+.\+"$/` -find all lines that at their ends have '*file.py*', '*one or more white spaces*', '*one or more strings*', and '"'(double quote).
`\1` -this replaces the first (and the only one in this case) sub-expression `(file.py)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's do `sed` for beginners:

You probably know the `s`ubstitude command to replace text like `s/old/new/`. Now your string ARG is unknown, so need to find something characteristic. For example, it's at the end of a line, only followed by a double quote and it consists of only alphanumeric characters? Great! Use the `[:alnum:]` character class and the `$´ anchor to the line ending:

```
sed 's/[[:alnum:]]*"$/new"/'
```

But this should only be applied on the `file.py` line. `sed` uses addresses for this, which can be line numbers or `/patterns/` preceeding the command:

```
sed '/file.py/s/[[:alnum:]]*"$/new"/'
```